# Query priority in SQLite

Tags: performance, cocoa, sqlite, macos

When performing a lot of queries in a short time span, I have noticed that it takes quite a bit of time (delay) before some queries are executed. Based on my testing, it seems that some queries are put in a queue and are therefore delayed.

Basically, I am working with two types of queries: (1) queries that need to be executed as quick as possible (they are linked to a timeout timer that cancels the operation when it takes to long) and (2) queries that are executed in the background in an automated way (and over which I have less control).

Is there a way to gain more control over the process of which query gains priority? Can I make sure (using SQLite) that the type 1 queries are executed when they come in and the type 2 queries are put on hold (until the type 1 queries are finished)?

For your information, I am using Gus Mueller's FMDB wrapper to interface with SQLite.

Comment: "(1) queries that need to be executed as quick as possible (they are linked to a timeout timer that cancels the operation when it takes to long)" -  that seems a unusual method. If an operation emits a query, surely you want it to complete? Suggest you put effort into speeding up queries (where possible)...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Mitch. The thing is that I have no control over the queries of type 2. I think I'll just have to look for another solution. However, thanks for your input.